# Calculate date differences, max and min date, and date counts using Pandas dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following dataset, with multiple patient_IDs and treatment Dates per patient_ID:

| Patient_ID | Dates |
| --- | --- |
| 2038 | 2012-01-02 |
| 2038 | 2012-02-13 |
| 2038 | 2012-02-27 |
| 2120 | 2005-02-05 |
| 2120 | 2009-03-31 |

What I want to do is:

A) extract per patient the total duration under treatment, then

B) save the maximum and minimum treatment Date (per patient_ID), and

C) finally count the number of treatments (Dates) per patient_ID.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
df=Patient_Dates
df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'])
grouped = df.groupby(['Patient_ID'])
op = []
for Name, group in grouped:
    LengthOfTreatment_days = group['Dates'].max() - group['Dates'].min()
    op.append([Name, LengthOfTreatment_days])
```

This counts A) in days fine. However, I can't find a way to perform B) and C) above.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please don't post your data as screenshots. You had the table before your edit and I've reverted it back. Change the data (within the text) if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `groupby` and `agg`:

```
output = df.groupby("Patient_ID")["Dates"].agg(max_date="max", min_date="min", num_treatments="count")
output["duration"] = (output["max_date"]-output["min_date"]).dt.days

>>> output
             max_date   min_date  num_treatments  duration
Patient_ID                                                
2038       2012-02-27 2012-01-02               3        56
2120       2009-03-31 2005-02-05               2      1515
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you not_speshal, it worked! One last question, how can I bring the column names all the same row (Patient_ID is one row lower vs max_date)? I tried to use iloc but it did not work.

Comment: To answer my last question, I know how to do it now: output2=output.reset_index()